# Unicode From Urllib2 request

Tags: python, unicode

I'm using urllib2 to send post request so part of the result contains
Unicode example : \u10dc\u10d0\u10d7\u10d8\u10d0

So I want my code to decode this text, any ideas?

I tried this text = "\u10dc\u10d0\u10d7\u10d8\u10d0"
text.decode('utf-8') but it didn't work

My code looks like this:

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, data=data, headers=request_headers)
request.get_method = lambda: method
connection = opener.open(request)
data = connection.read()
print data
```

Comment: When you say "it didn't work", what exactly happened? Was there an exception? Data corruption?

Comment: can you say what is the url you're hitting or what is the output it's giving.

Comment: `print u.decode('unicode-escape')` -> `ნათია`